SQL command not properly ended when using Page in Spring
I'm trying to use findAll method to get data by Page using Spring 3.3.5 and Oracle 11g, i'm getting error ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended :
Page<StepsData> dataPage = dataRepository.findAll(PageRequest.of(page, size))

pom file :
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.oracle.database.jdbc</groupId>
            <artifactId>ojdbc8</artifactId>
            <version>21.5.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.orm</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>6.4.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>

properties file :
db.oracle.jdbc.driver=oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.OracleDialect

Error :

org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: JDBC
exception executing SQL [select
sd1_0.id,sd1_0.CALORIES,sd1_0.DATE_TIME,sd1_0.DISTANCE,sd1_0.DURATION,sd1_0.STEP_DATE,sd1_0.STEPS,sd1_0.TARGET_STEPS,sd1_0.TIME,sd1_0.USER_ID
from STEPS_DATA sd1_0 offset ? rows fetch first ? rows only]
[ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended ] [n/a]; SQL [n/a]


Please include oracle jdbc version(pom/gradle) and oracle database version.

Show your dependencies, your application.properties and further configuration that might be useful. When doing so please use proper formatting and not quote tags but code tags!.

Remove hibernate-core dependency and only make sure you have spring-boot-starter-data-jpa.

i just updated question, im using oracle 11g

same error when hibernate-core is remived

Try changing your Hibernate dialect to org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect.

i got error Could not load requested class : org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect
